# Django + Cloud Firestore CRED not working - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory // NameError: name 'database' is not defined

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-firestore, django-views

Anyone familiar with Django and Firestore? I would highly appreciate help. I'm troubleshooting an Error for hours and I guess I'm not able to fix it.

It somehow can't find my cred Certificate altough its 100% located at the given path.

XXX = censored

```py
firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
authe = firebase.auth()


cred = credentials.Certificate("G:\Python Programme\Keys\XXX.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {"https://XXX-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"})
database = firestore.client()
```

Now the Error is: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'G:\Python Programme\Keys\XXX.json'
Now, the weird thing is if I create a try except to see the actual error it works without an Error but I do get a Problem when actually writing into the db:

```py
try:
        cred = credentials.Certificate("G:\Python Programme\Keys\XXX.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {"https://XXX-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"})
        database = firestore.client()
except BaseException as e:
    print("Error ist: ")
    print(e)
```

NameError: name 'database' is not defined

Django View:

```py
def postSignUp(request):
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    passw = request.POST.get('pass')

    try:
        user=authe.create_user_with_email_and_password(email,passw)
    except:
        message="User exists already - please sign in."
        return render(request, "signUp.html", {"messg":message})
    

    isBusinessClient=False
    uid = user['localId']
    data = {"name":name, "email":email, "isBusinessClient": isBusinessClient,}
    
    #database.child("users").child(uid).child("details").set(data) alter Code 
    doc_ref=database.collection('User').document()
    doc_ref.set(data)

    return render(request, "welcome.html", {"e":email})
```

I was expecting an Error when using try except. I was expecting the view to acutally write into the firestore cloud.

Comment: In addition when I try to remove the "database = firestore.client()" out of the try after the except I do get: ValueError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure to initialize the SDK by calling initialize_app().

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to solve this issue. Weird thing but you have to initialize firebase for authentication after the cred.

I did place the Key (cred) in the Django Views folder. This code is now working:

```py
cred = credentials.Certificate("XXX.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)


database = firestore.client()

firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
authe = firebase.auth()
```